# SQL Server 2012 Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I was reading through Kendra Little's post on www.brentozar.com

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/query-plans-what-happens-when-row-estimates-get-high/

In the post, Kendra mentioned that she is using SQL Server 2012. Kendra has displayed a execution plan mouse over pop up as shown below, with more information like Memory Grants. [image: Select [plan estimate]
[image: Memory Grant Conversion].

I am also using SQL Server 2012 (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)) . 
But I am getting a different information as below.

[image: SELECT]

Anybody have any idea what am my missing ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe Kendra is using a front end application called SQL Sentry Plan Explorer.  It's a really great tool and gives a little bit more verbose info about the execution plan.  Here's an example of a query I'm working on right now with Plan Explorer:

[image]

It's also free-ninety-nine! (the paid version gives you some more bells and whistles but the free version is fantastic for basic execution plan review).  It's one of my favorite tools in my DBA toolbelt, for sure.

Link to product: http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view

Comment: Added the link!

Comment: Hi Kris, Thank you very much for looking at it. But even in the screenshot you attached, there are no memory Grant information. Does it rings any bell ?

Do you think Kendra is using the full version of SQL Sentry Plan explorer ?